# Endless loop on Up button in Settings Activity - large tablets only

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-developer-api

I'm having problems with SettingsActivity which was generated by Android Studio.  Specifically pressing the Up button creates a new instance of settings activity  instead of going back to the parent activity.  This happens only on large tablets where settings are split - i.e. headers to the left of the list of settings.

The following code was generated by Android Studio:

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

On large tablets onMenuItemSelected() always returns true so navigateUpFromSameTask() is never called.  However, even forcing the call to navigateUpFromSameTask() produces the same results.

Example:

```
...
        if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item) || 
                isXLargeTablet(this)) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
...
```

The only thing that seems to work is a call to finish().
Example:

```
   if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        if (isXLargeTablet(this)) {
           finish();
           return true;
        }
        if (!super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item)) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The parent activity's (main activity) launchMode is set to "singleTop" in the manifest.

The same navigation works fine on smaller tablets and phones.

I'm not sure if my hacky solution is sufficient.
Is there another way to deal with this 'bug'?

Thanks.